# hci_write_local_name to write BLE name

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

It's not clear what the behaviour of `hci_write_local_name` should be. I'm using this function to change the local name of my BLE device but when I scan the network I see the device with original name (I checked the mac address to confirm) although the `hci_read_local_name` returns the written name.

Comment: first things first, 'hci_read_local_name' is not an official name from the Bluetooth specification. Which OS/Library we are talking about?

Comment: If we are talking about `HCI_Write_Local_Name`, the specification is specific about it:
*The HCI_Write_Local_Name command provides the ability to modify the userfriendly
name for the BR/EDR Controller. See Section 6.23.*. This function applies to the Bluetooth Classic interface.

Comment: If you want to modify the <<Complete local name>>, then you need to modify the corresponding AD structure  in the *Advertising* or *Scan Response* PDU.

Comment: @Risto ... Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy does not use that command. That command is for Bluetooth Classic (i.e. BR/EDR).